# While statement causing freeze/crash in LibGDX?

Tags: while-loop, libgdx

I have the following code in the update method of a base level class:

```
while(entities.iterator().hasNext()){
        if(entities.iterator().next() != null){
            entities.iterator().next().update();
            Gdx.app.log(Game.LOG, "Updated Entity "+entities.iterator().next().getName()+".");
        }
        else{
            Gdx.app.log(Game.LOG, "Could not update Entity.");
        }
    }
```

However, this statement will freeze the program when it is run, and will have to be force closed without providing any crash information. I can stop the freezing by using an if statement instead of a while, however, it will only update the first entity in the array.

What could be causing the freeze, and how can the iterator be looped without causing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call the iterator() and next() methods more than required. The iterator() method will reset the iterator on every call. The next() method will fetch the next item on every call. Instead use something like this:

```
Iterator<T> iterator = entities.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    T entity = iterator.next();
    entity.update();
}
```

Where T should be replaced by the class of your entity.

Edit, easier would be using the syntactic sugar:

```
for (T entity : entities) {
    entity.update();
}
```

Comment: The for loop was able to handle the entities, thanks! I wasn't aware that Java could use a for loop like that.